# How to explain the difference between "There's a table" and "It is a table"?

Tags: meaning, pronouns, existentials

What is the difference between '**There's** a table' and **'It is** a table'?

Comment: For the existential *"There's a table"* to be acceptable, then there is the pragmatic constraint that the table is supposed to be new information, a type of new info where the speaker assumes that the info "a table" is new to the hearer. But if the word "there" is a locative deictic "there" (the usual "pointing" there), then there is no such constraint. Nor is *"It is a table"* under that constraint either; and it would depend on the context as to how it could be interpreted as to its construction. -- And so, you really probably ought to provide a context for those sentences.

Comment: Also, it might be difficult to create a context where the existential *"There's a table"* would be acceptable. The difficulty is that there isn't much info in that post-verbal noun phrase (PVNP). More usual types of existentials could be stuff like: *"There's a table on the bottom of the swimming pool"*, *"There's a table up in the attic. Will you please get it for me?"* -- EDIT: But it might work if the context has already been established where stuff is being implied.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. **There's** a table.

This is an existential construction. You are telling your reader that somewhere a table **exists**.

> - Don't ride on your bicycle in that room! **There's a table.** You might collide with the table.
> - "What did you see inside that room?" - "Well, **there's** a table. **There's** a chair. And **there's** also a big TV set."

Now,

> 2. **It is** a table

You are explaining to the reader that **it** is a table. Your reader sees **it** but he does not know what that is.

> - Can you see a **white rectangle** inside the room? **It** is a table. **It** is covered with white linen.
> - "What is **this** on this picture?" (pointing with a finger)  - "**It is** a table".

Answer (score 0):

Probably the situations of such statements are different.

A learner who beginns to learn English nouns may point at a table and ask 
What is it? -- Teacher: It's a table.

A waiter may say to a colleague, we need an additional table for the breakfast room. The colleague may answer: There is a table you can take.